# Docker compose duplicit variables

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Example snippets from my files:

docker-compose.yaml:

```
 services:
  banana:
    container_name: banana
    hostname: banana
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/pycharm/Dockerfile
      args:
        B_LOGIN: ${B_LOGIN}
        B_TOKEN: ${B_TOKEN}
        LOG_LEVEL: INFO
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: INFO
      PYTHONPATH: /workspace
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspace:cached
    command: sleep infinity
```

Dockefile:

```
ARG B_LOGIN
ARG B_TOKEN
ARG LOG_LEVEL

RUN echo "${B_LOGIN}, ${B_TOKEN}, ${LOG_LEVEL}"

...
```

.env:

```
B_LOGIN="aaaa"
B_TOKEN="bbbb"
```

Then in my app, I use `os.getenv("LOG_LEVEL", "DEBUG")` to get log level.

If I have my `LOG_LEVEL` set only in the `args:` and not the `environment:`variables in my `docker-compose.yaml`, then `LOG_LEVEL` doesn't get set to `INFO`.
Is there a way to set `LOG_LEVEL` once, not in both `environment:` and `args:` inside my `docker-compose.yaml`?

I need to pass `LOG_LEVEL` to my Dockerfile as well as use it in my app.

I would like it if it was possible for all variables to not be duplicit in my `docker-compose.yaml` and then use them in Dockerfile and my app.

Comment: You can put it to .env to avoid value duplication, then use `LOG_LEVEL: $LOG_LEVEL` in args and environment sections. You can use ENV instruction in Dockerfile to set envvar without `environment` entry.

Comment: So if I want a var to be used at build time as well as run time, I should add it to build args: and then to environment: or set in Dockerfile ENV? What if I want to be able to change the var without running Docker compose again? Would only the ENV change and args: not change?

Answer (score 1):

ARG sets a value at build time. You probably want to set the variables at run-time, so you can change your login and token values without building the image again.

To do that, define the variables as environment variables in the docker compose file like this

```
 services:
  banana:
    container_name: banana
    hostname: banana
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/pycharm/Dockerfile
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: INFO
      PYTHONPATH: /workspace
      B_LOGIN: ${B_LOGIN}
      B_TOKEN: ${B_TOKEN}
      LOG_LEVEL: INFO
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspace:cached
    command: sleep infinity
```

The variables won't be available at build time, so you can't echo them using a RUN statement, since that runs at build time. But they will be available at run-time for your application.

You don't need to define environment variables in your Dockerfile and since the RUN statement won't work, you can delete the 4 statements of your Dockerfile that you have in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The echo command was just an example. The B_LOGIN and password are only necessary once to get libraries, so I guess build time variables?  I am using log_level for setting an alias for a behave command. I guess I could set the alias someplace other than the Dockerfile, but don't know where. Also would need to use it at runtime, so would prefer only as runtime var.